# A faster way to get data from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I recently uploaded 37,000 strings of data to Firebase (name of all cities in USA). To find that it takes way too long to go through each one using the observe .childAdded method to upload it to a basic table view.

Is there an alternative? How can I get the data to my app faster?  The data shouldn’t change.... so is there an alternative?

Comment: I hope you are not reading 37k of documents at once... If you want to display them, use a query limit and and only pull maybe 50, then another 50 etc.. 
What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @arvidurs Something similar to google place autocomplete. So when someone is in the “text field” typing in “new yor” it can suggest “New York city” etc. any ideas? I basically have an array, but it’s taking literally minutes for it to grab all 37,000 cities.

Comment: I would only start looking after the user entered at least three characters, this will narrow the search significantly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to load the same data faster. Firebase isn't artificially throttling your download speed, so the time it takes to read the 37,000 strings, is he time it takes to read the 37,000 strings.

To make your application respond faster to the user, you will have to load less data. And since it's unlikely your user will read all 37,000 strings, a good first option is to only load the data that they will see.

Since you're describing an auto-complete scenario, I'd first look at using a query to only retrieve child nodes that match what they already typed. In Firebase that'd be something like this:

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
   .queryStarting(atValue: "stack")
   .queryEnding(atValue: "stack\u{f8ff}")
```

This code takes (on the server) all nodes under `ref`, and orders them by name. It then finds the first one starting with `stack` and returns all child nodes until it finds one not starting with `stack` anymore.

With this approach the filtering happens on the server, and the client only has to download the data that matches the query.

Answer (score 0):

This is something easily solvable using [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/). Algolia can search large data sets without taking much time at all. This way, you query Algolia and never need to look at the Firebase database.

In your **Firebase Functions**, listen for any new nodes in the place you keep your names of cities, and when that function gets called, add that string to your Algolia index.

You can follow the Algolia docs here: [Algolia Docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/)